# What is a word for "determine oneself"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, translation

There is a Greek verb (*αὐτοκαθορίζομαι*) that I constantly translate as *determine oneself* and which proof readers constantly replace with other irrelevant verbs that they think fit the context. The verb is supposed to mean

> decide/determine one's own position, one's attitude or disposition (mainly before God in my contexts), decide "where one stands" (determining oneself before God can be either positive or negative).

This is precisely the meaning I am looking for. Is there an idiomatic way to express this?

Here are 2 examples I encountered while translating:

> - Isaiah says that when Emmanuel is born, before even learning to discern his right hand from the left, he will ***determine himself*** for God in an irreversible and definitive way (see Isa. 7:15-16).
> - Their state depends on how they ***determine themselves*** before God.

In the last example, the proof reader suggested *present* instead of *determine*, but then my translation is no longer accurate.

***Determine oneself*** (as a reflexive verb) is [not easy to find in dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=determine%20oneself%20meaning&oq=determine%20oneself&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30j0i15i22i30l3j0i390l3.7280j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The nearest hit I got was ***self-determination***:

> determination by oneself or itself, without outside influence; freedom to live as one chooses, or to act or decide without consulting another or others.([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-determination#:%7E:text=noun,without%20consulting%20another%20or%20others.))

If *determine oneself* sounds awkward, is there another verb or phrase that can express this?

Comment: Could you give the actual quote and precise reference for the statement you say is from Isaiah, please? The verb 'commit [oneself to God]' is often used for resolving to obey the general and more specific commands of God, at least in Christian circles.

Comment: Done. Note that the KJV is different from the Greek text. I find the version LXE (English translation of the Septuagint) more accurate.

Comment: Not just the KJV, but all the many translations [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/7-15.htm) (in the first instance) fail to have 'he will determine himself for God in an irreversible and definitive way' or anything like it. // 'Consecrate oneself' may well be the answer, but I feel this would be better on Biblical Hermeneutics.SE (or Christianity.SE).

Comment: Yes, "commit" would be good in the first sentence, you are right. But most of my contexts have "before God"... "Commit oneself before God" doesn't really go.

Comment: I would rather have a linguistic approach. I am looking for a word fit for the meaning. I am not looking for a concept.

Comment: 'Consecrate oneself to God' or 'Commit [oneself] to follow God's will for one's life'. / 'I would rather have a linguistic approach' ... But these terms have far deeper ramifications as used say in Christian circles.

Comment: "Determine oneself" (as a reflexive verb) is "not easy to find in dictionaries" because ***It's not an idiomatically established usage in English***. The two examples you cite seem to be just your own text as posted on another website. You need to give a clear definition of *exactly* the sense you want. Perhaps (definitely) "**commit** / dedicate oneself" to some higher power? Or (tentatively) "**decide** whether one wants to make any such commitment"? We can't guess that part - only you know what the badly translated greek expression means.

Comment: (I seriously doubt that the noun "self-determination" has anything to do with the intended sense here; that's to do with people being able to choose their own leaders, rather than being "enslaved" by foreign rulers.)

Comment: Less of this, more of that. It seems unlikely there's a single verb in English with whatever precise meaning you seek - but if there *is* such a word, it'll probably be "domain-specific" (only known to and used by Christian theologians?). I'm not a theologian, so I don't really understand what you're getting at with *more about defining oneself as something before God.*

Comment: I told *you* what "self-determination" means! I also told you that "determine oneself" has ***no established meaning*** in English.

Comment: This is an awful lot of commenting without getting anywhere. Can you not edit the question to give a clear definition of the *exact* meaning you seek? Just because we might not have a single English word doesn't mean the concept can't be described fully and accurately in English.

Comment: Too much comment, opinion and dispute; too little answer. Close as a matter of opinion.

Comment: Does it mean to reach a decision, or to declare that you have reached a decision? What was your state before the decision (secrecy, indifference, indecision/equivocation...)? There are various phrases such as "take a stand", "declare yourself for/against", "reach a decision", "state your position", "nail your colours to the mast", "get off the fence", "choose a side", etc, one of which is likely to have the meaning you want (English often uses phrases where many languages use a single, long word, which is why the single-word-request tag is stupid) but it's not terribly clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

["Gauge" or "Gage"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gauge):(Collins Dictionary) If you gauge people's actions, feelings, or intentions in a particular situation, you carefully consider and judge them.

[Proclaim](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proclaim):(Collins Dictionary) If you proclaim something, you state it in an emphatic way.

[Appraise](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appraise):(Collins Dictionary) If you appraise something or someone, you consider them carefully and form an opinion about them.

The two example sentences would become

> Isaiah says that when Emmanuel is born, before even learning to
> discern his right hand from the left, he will **proclaim** himself for
> God in an irreversible and definitive way.
>
> Their state depends on how
> they **proclaim** themselves before God.

Comment: Proclaiming is the closest to what I need. The other two options I find irrelevant. "Proclaiming oneself" as something... Still looking.

Answer (score 1):

*[Resolved](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/resolve)*

There are a few senses here that may triangulate the connotation you're looking for:

1. to reach as a decision or intention; determine ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/resolve))
2. firm determination to do something ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=resolve%20definition))
3. decide firmly on a course of action (Oxford Languages)
4. to make a decision about (Collins)

Presenting yourself, proclaiming yourself--those seem to affirm your resolve to do something.

There may not be a direct translation that satisfies all needs here, I present this as something that may box in most relevant parts.

Comment: Yes, resolution is a strong connotation that I need. Right now suggestions drove me to thinking about _positioning oneself for or against God_. But it is a bit wordy...